# Loading large data

Tags: c#, nhibernate, devexpress

I hava a datatable with large amount of data (250K).
I have used DevExpress component and nhibernate.
In devexpress components is server mode, but it does not suit me because I am using nHibernate.
In the table is many column as well. And 5 relation tables which displays together with main table (250K records).
 What a best way to advise me to achieve the goal?
Thanks and sorry for my English.

**EDIT:**
How to implement loading data with small portions?

Comment: What's the question? Can you be more precise in what you are trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood your question, you probably need pagination: loading and displaying data in chunks. NHibernate supports this with ICreteria and a combination of SetFirstResult/SetMaxResults:

```
IList<MyObject> GetPageOfMyObjects(int pageSize, int zeroBasedPageNumber) {

    return Session.CreateCriteria(typeof (MyObject))
                    .SetFirstResult(pageSize*(pageNumber))
                    .SetMaxResults(pageSize)
                    .List<MyObject>();

}
```

Comment: Yes, but i did other way: SetFirstResult(0).SetMaxResult(LastRecord). And I have increment LastRecord when it needed.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use paging. 
Also check if the devExpress ctx supports virtual paging with object data source so they can handle automatically the paging.